# Shortcut to path with symbol linux

Tags: linux, path, terminal, shortcut, symbols

Is it possible to make a custom linux terminal shortcut for a certain path, like ~ refers to the home directory? I.e I want to link # to /media/hd2/randomfolder. So that #/test.c would link to a file in the /media/hd2/randomfolder directory.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Yes, but be prepared for an uphill battle.

Comment: I came up with kind of a (not so satisfying) solution. I made a very short named symbolic link to the desired folder and placed it in the home folder.